# Update contents of column header in slickgrid

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid in an angular application which supports multiple languages. How can I update the column headers when the selected language is changed.
My column definition looks like this and what I basically want is the grid to call myI18N again to update the column title.

```
{ id: "myid", name: myI18nFn('idKey'), field: "myid", width: 100}
```

I have an angular event that detects changes and I have access to the grid object there, I am just not sure on what I need to do make it update the column header

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `colDef.name` property when the language changes and then trigger the grid to rebuild the header row (which occurs in the `createColumnHeaders` method in the SlickGrid source). The easiest way is to just update the column list with a `setColumns` call, which triggers a rerender of the entire grid:

```
function updateColumnHeaders()
{
    var cols = grid.getColumns();
    for(var i = 0, il = cols.length; i < il; i++)
    {
        cols[i].name = myI18nFn(cols[i].id);
    }
    grid.setColumns(cols);
}
```